Seeking Guidance on Integrating Checkstyle with Ant Build Script in Java Project within Visual Studio Code .Advice on Checkstyle in Ant Script for
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check
The import com.puppycrawl cannot be resolvedJava(268435846)
I am currently working on a Java project where I'm using Ant as the build tool and Visual Studio Code as the IDE. I'm encountering difficulties integrating Checkstyle into my Ant build script.
Specifically, I'm struggling with ensuring that the Checkstyle task in the Ant script references the correct classpath, including the Checkstyle JAR file. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
How to properly configure the Checkstyle task in the Ant script to include the Checkstyle JAR file?
